# GPS + IMU Fusion filter

Tags: c, arduino, gps, kalman-filter, imu

I have a question. I have a twin-engine boat and I want to implement an autopilot in it. Using GPS alone my boat goes to the destination like a sine wave, unfortunately for 300m. Just like the picture below.
[image]

I Use RadioLink M8N GPS SE100 (http://radiolink.com.cn/doce/UploadFile/ProductFile/SE100Manual.pdf) and STM32. It has a built-in geomagnetic sensor HMC5983. Is it possible to use this sensor and GPS to let my boat go straight?

I don't know much about all those Kalman filters, Fusion, etc.
My question is what should I use, apart from the GPS itself, what kind of sensors and filters to make my boat sail in a straight line.

Thanks in advance for the tips and hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to position a boat. If you only use poor GPS receiver, you couldn't do this. In order to solve this, you should apply UKF(unscented kalman filter) with fusion of GPS and INS.

Answer (score 0):

According to ublox [documentation](https://content.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/u-blox8-M8_ReceiverDescrProtSpec_UBX-13003221.pdf) it is possible to enable fusion filter for M8N and feed the data to it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32945965)